# Flask peewee AttributeError: 'ModelSelect' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I have a very simple setup, a model and api file in a pipenv flask environment. I'm currently using peewee and been facing an issue with getting all results from a datatable. I've done this before in python and works fine however not sure what in Flask I'm doing wrong. Here is my model

```
from peewee import * 
import peewee as pw


db = pw.MySQLDatabase('xxxxx', host="localhost", port=3306, user='xxx', 
password="xxxxx")


class HomeCarousel(Model):
   icon = pw.CharField(100)
   header = pw.CharField(50)
   text = pw.CharField(100)
   class Meta:
      database = db
```

and here is my api file

```
from flask import Flask, g
from flask import jsonify, make_response
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict
from peewee import *
import peewee as pw
from models import *
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/')
def index():
   items = HomeCarousel.select()
   items = model_to_dict(items)
   return items

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now the issue is that when I do `items = HomeCarousel.select()` I get an error "AttributeError: 'ModelSelect' object has no attribute '_meta'"

If I select only one record, everything works just fine.  `items = HomeCarousel.get()`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model_to_dict expects an object instance.  You're passing it a [ModelSelect](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#ModelSelect).  You need to iterate over the objects returned in your ModelSelect:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   items = HomeCarousel.select()
   items = [model_to_dict(item) for item in items]
   return items
```